# Assertion does not fail for list with lenghty element in Spock when run via IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, spock, assertions

The following test always passes for me in Spock 1.1-groovy-2.4 in IntelliJ 2017.3 on Windows:

```
def "broken assertion"() {
    expect:
    [('a' * 600_000)].first() == 'b'
}
```

What's even more surprising, the following fails as expected:

```
def "broken assertion"() {
    expect:
    [('a' * 600_000)].first().equals('b')
}
```

Error message:

```
[('a' * 600_000)].first().equals('b')
      |           |       |
      |           |       false
      |           aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
      aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa...
```

Also, the test fails as expecten when run from command line. It passes only in IntelliJ IDEA.

**How this could be explained?**

---

**EDIT**

In `idea.log` I see the following exception:

```
2018-01-30 12:54:49,518 [1917092061]  ERROR - utToGeneralTestEventsConverter - [JUnit]: Error parsing text: [##teamcity[testFailed name='ListTessSpaceNexusVersionsTest.broken assertion' duration='303' details='|r|n  at Test.broken assertion(Test.groovy:32)|r|n' message='Condition not satisfied:|n|n|[(|'a|' * 523_999)|].first() == |'b|'|n      ||           ||       |||n      ||           ||       false|n      ||           ||       Strings too large to calculate edit distance.|n      ||           aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<...>actualFile='C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\actual1055937705826402150' actualIsTempFile='true']
] 
java.text.ParseException: Incorrect property name.
Valid property list format is (name( )*=( )*'escaped_value'( )*)* where escape simbol is "|"
    at jetbrains.buildServer.messages.serviceMessages.MapSerializerUtil.checkPropName(MapSerializerUtil.java:84)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.messages.serviceMessages.MapSerializerUtil.stringToProperties(MapSerializerUtil.java:56)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.messages.serviceMessages.ServiceMessage.parseAttributes(ServiceMessage.java:298)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.messages.serviceMessages.ServiceMessage.init(ServiceMessage.java:423)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.messages.serviceMessages.ServiceMessage.doParse(ServiceMessage.java:375)
    at jetbrains.buildServer.messages.serviceMessages.ServiceMessage.parse(ServiceMessage.java:119)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.processServiceMessages(OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.java:142)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.processConsistentText(OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.java:99)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter$1.onLineAvailable(OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.java:53)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputLineSplitter.a(OutputLineSplitter.java:158)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputLineSplitter.b(OutputLineSplitter.java:111)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputLineSplitter.a(OutputLineSplitter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputLineSplitter.process(OutputLineSplitter.java:53)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.process(OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.java:71)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.SMTestRunnerConnectionUtil$2.onTextAvailable(SMTestRunnerConnectionUtil.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor209.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler$5.invoke(ProcessHandler.java:239)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.onTextAvailable(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ProcessHandler.java:213)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ColoredProcessHandler.textAvailable(ColoredProcessHandler.java:96)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ColoredProcessHandler.coloredTextAvailable(ColoredProcessHandler.java:71)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.AnsiEscapeDecoder.processTextChunk(AnsiEscapeDecoder.java:267)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.AnsiEscapeDecoder.escapeText(AnsiEscapeDecoder.java:67)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.ColoredProcessHandler.notifyTextAvailable(ColoredProcessHandler.java:60)
    at com.intellij.execution.process.BaseOSProcessHandler$SimpleOutputReader.onTextAvailable(BaseOSProcessHandler.java:295)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.sendText(BaseOutputReader.java:202)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.processInput(BaseOutputReader.java:186)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseOutputReader.readAvailableNonBlocking(BaseOutputReader.java:105)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader.readAvailable(BaseDataReader.java:85)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader.doRun(BaseDataReader.java:163)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader$1$1.run(BaseDataReader.java:66)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:194)
    at com.intellij.util.io.BaseDataReader$1.run(BaseDataReader.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Fails as expected - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wololock/a23285751462ffab5cf15522a95ea206/raw/f725b9349043a7a2afc365342cc8bd05ac082ea7/BrokenAssertionSpec.groovy Spock `org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4`

Comment: That's interesting, looks like env-related issue. Can you try for higher numbers like `1_000_000`?

Comment: Lenght doesn't matter. I can use `1_000_000_000` and get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. I assume your test expectation is broken - you compare with `b` the whole string. `[('a' * 600_000)]` produces a single element list with a long string. When you call `.first()` you get that string, not the first character from it. Are you sure your test get executed? When you run this test with a debugger - can you access breakpoint at this line of code?

Comment: Looks like it is issue with IntelliJ (I'm using 2017.3). In debug mode everything is fine and `org.junit.runner.Result#wasSuccessful` returns `false`, but still the test is shown as passed. When run from command line it fails as expected.

Comment: In my case it failed in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.3. Failed in Gradle as well.

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows? In my `idea.log` I found interesting exception, now I need to find root cause of it.

Comment: Linux (Fedora Linux 26)

Comment: That may explain, I'm getting this issue with IDEA just on Windows. I cannot find code of `jetbrains.buildServer.messages.serviceMessages.MapSerializerUtil.checkPropName` to check what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 2):

It's IntelliJ IDEA bug most probably. You can add following dependencies manually to your's project classpath to see decompiled classes from your stacktrace:

- `{{IDEA root}}/lib/idea.jar`
- `{{IDEA root}}/lib/serviceMessages.jar`

Below you can find `checkPropName` and `stringToProperties` methods from top of your stacktrace:

```
@NotNull
public static Map<String, String> stringToProperties(@NotNull String string, @NotNull MapSerializerUtil.EscapeInfoProvider escaper, boolean strictNameCheck) throws ParseException {
    String currentString = string;
    LinkedHashMap result = new LinkedHashMap();

    while(currentString.length() > 0) {
        int nameSep = currentString.indexOf("=");
        if (nameSep == -1) {
            throw new ParseException("Property value not found\nValid property list format is (name( )*=( )*'escaped_value'( )*)* where escape simbol is \"|\"", 0);
        }

        String name = currentString.substring(0, nameSep).trim();
        checkPropName(name, strictNameCheck);
        currentString = currentString.substring(nameSep + 1).trim();
        if (!currentString.startsWith("'")) {
            throw new ParseException("Value should start with \"'\"\nValid property list format is (name( )*=( )*'escaped_value'( )*)* where escape simbol is \"|\"", 0);
        }

        currentString = currentString.substring(1);
        int endOfValue = indexOf(currentString, '\'', escaper);
        if (endOfValue < 0) {
            throw new ParseException("Value should end with \"'\"\nValid property list format is (name( )*=( )*'escaped_value'( )*)* where escape simbol is \"|\"", 0);
        }

        String escapedValue = currentString.substring(0, endOfValue);
        currentString = currentString.substring(endOfValue + 1).trim();
        result.put(name, unescapeStr(escapedValue, escaper));
    }

    return result;
}

private static void checkPropName(String name, boolean strict) throws ParseException {
    boolean isCorrect = strict ? isValidJavaIdentifier(name) : !hasSpaces(name);
    if (!isCorrect) {
        throw new ParseException("Incorrect property name.\nValid property list format is (name( )*=( )*'escaped_value'( )*)* where escape simbol is \"|\"", 0);
    }
}
```

The main problem is that input string that `stringToProperties` retrieves is following:

```
testFailed name='ListTessSpaceNexusVersionsTest.broken assertion' duration='303' details='|r|n  at Test.broken assertion(Test.groovy:32)|r|n' message='Condition not satisfied:|n|n|[(|'a|' * 523_999)|].first() == |'b|'|n      ||           ||       |||n      ||           ||       false|n      ||           ||       Strings too large to calculate edit distance.|n      ||           aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<...>actualFile='C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\actual1055937705826402150' actualIsTempFile='true'
```

and here is the problematic part:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<...>actualFile='C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\actual1055937705826402150' actualIsTempFile='true'
```

`messages` property does not get escaped properly. It should be completed after `<...>` because `actualFile='C:\...` defines next property.

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<...>123' actualFile='C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\actual1055937705826402150' actualIsTempFile='true'
```

What happens is IDEA cuts message string if it is longer than console's cycle buffer size (1024 KB by default):

```
protected void processConsistentText(String text, final Key outputType, boolean tcLikeFakeOutput) {
  final int cycleBufferSize = ConsoleBuffer.getCycleBufferSize();
  if (USE_CYCLE_BUFFER && text.length() > cycleBufferSize) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(cycleBufferSize);
    builder.append(text, 0, cycleBufferSize - 105);
    builder.append("<...>");
    builder.append(text, text.length() - 100, text.length());
    text = builder.toString();
  }
  //....
  //....
}
```

When I run same test in my IntelliJ IDEA, console message string ends with:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<...>512
```

I suspect exactly same thing happens in your case, but somehow the input string that is passed to `stringToProperties` method gets broken earlier. If we look at the stacktrace we will find out that there is `OutputLineSplitter` class being used before final String gets passed to `stringToProperties` method.

```
    at jetbrains.buildServer.messages.serviceMessages.ServiceMessage.parse(ServiceMessage.java:119)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.processServiceMessages(OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.java:142)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.processConsistentText(OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.java:99)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter$1.onLineAvailable(OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.java:53)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputLineSplitter.a(OutputLineSplitter.java:158)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputLineSplitter.b(OutputLineSplitter.java:111)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputLineSplitter.a(OutputLineSplitter.java:80)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputLineSplitter.process(OutputLineSplitter.java:53)
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.process(OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.java:71)
```

Source code of this class can be found on Github: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/smRunner/src/com/intellij/execution/testframework/sm/runner/OutputLineSplitter.java Below you can find decompiled version as well:

```
package com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner;

import com.intellij.execution.process.ProcessOutputTypes;
import com.intellij.openapi.util.Key;
import gnu.trove.THashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public abstract class OutputLineSplitter {
    private static final String c = "##teamcity[";
    public static final int TC_MESSAGE_LENGTH = "##teamcity[".length();
    private final boolean d;
    private final Map<Key, StringBuilder> a = new THashMap();
    private final List<OutputLineSplitter.OutputChunk> b = new ArrayList();

    public OutputLineSplitter(boolean var1) {
        this.a.put(ProcessOutputTypes.SYSTEM, new StringBuilder());
        this.a.put(ProcessOutputTypes.STDERR, new StringBuilder());
        this.d = var1;
    }

    public void process(String var1, Key var2) {
        int var3 = 0;
        int var4 = 0;
        boolean var5 = true;

        for(int var6 = 0; var6 < var1.length(); ++var6) {
            char var7 = var1.charAt(var6);
            if (var7 == '\n') {
                this.b(var1.substring(var3, var6 + 1), var2);
                var3 = var6 + 1;
                var5 = true;
            } else if (!var5 && var7 == "##teamcity[".charAt(var4)) {
                ++var4;
                if (var4 == TC_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
                    int var8 = var6 + 1 - TC_MESSAGE_LENGTH;
                    this.b(var1.substring(var3, var8), var2);
                    this.flush();
                    var3 = var8;
                    var4 = 0;
                }
            } else {
                var4 = var7 == "##teamcity[".charAt(0) ? 1 : 0;
                var5 = false;
            }
        }

        if (var3 < var1.length()) {
            this.b(var1.substring(var3), var2);
        }

    }

    private void b(String var1, Key var2) {
        if (!this.a.keySet().contains(var2)) {
            this.a(var1, var2);
        } else {
            StringBuilder var3 = (StringBuilder)this.a.get(var2);
            if (!var1.endsWith("\n")) {
                var3.append(var1);
                return;
            }

            if (var3.length() > 0) {
                var3.append(var1);
                var1 = var3.toString();
                var3.setLength(0);
            }

            this.onLineAvailable(var1, var2, false);
        }

    }

    private void a(String var1, Key var2) {
        int var3 = var1.length();
        if (var3 != 0) {
            List var4 = this.b;
            synchronized(this.b) {
                this.b.add(new OutputLineSplitter.OutputChunk(var2, var1));
            }

            char var7 = var1.charAt(var3 - 1);
            if (var7 != '\n' && var7 != '\r') {
                if (this.d && !this.isInTeamcityMessage()) {
                    this.a();
                }
            } else {
                this.a();
            }

        }
    }

    private void a() {
        ArrayList var1 = new ArrayList();
        OutputLineSplitter.OutputChunk var2 = null;
        List var3 = this.b;
        Iterator var4;
        OutputLineSplitter.OutputChunk var5;
        synchronized(this.b) {
            var4 = this.b.iterator();

            while(true) {
                if (!var4.hasNext()) {
                    this.b.clear();
                    break;
                }

                var5 = (OutputLineSplitter.OutputChunk)var4.next();
                if (var2 != null && var5.getKey() == var2.getKey()) {
                    var2.append(var5.getText());
                } else {
                    var2 = var5;
                    var1.add(var5);
                }
            }
        }

        boolean var8 = var1.size() == 1;
        var4 = var1.iterator();

        while(var4.hasNext()) {
            var5 = (OutputLineSplitter.OutputChunk)var4.next();
            this.onLineAvailable(var5.getText(), var5.getKey(), var8);
        }

    }

    public void flush() {
        this.a();
        Iterator var1 = this.a.entrySet().iterator();

        while(var1.hasNext()) {
            Entry var2 = (Entry)var1.next();
            StringBuilder var3 = (StringBuilder)var2.getValue();
            if (var3.length() > 0) {
                this.onLineAvailable(var3.toString(), (Key)var2.getKey(), false);
                var3.setLength(0);
            }
        }

    }

    protected boolean isInTeamcityMessage() {
        return this.b.stream().anyMatch((var0) -> {
            return var0.getText().startsWith("##teamcity[");
        });
    }

    protected abstract void onLineAvailable(@NotNull String var1, @NotNull Key var2, boolean var3);

    private static class OutputChunk {
        private final Key c;
        private String a;
        private StringBuilder b;

        private OutputChunk(Key var1, String var2) {
            this.c = var1;
            this.a = var2;
        }

        public Key getKey() {
            return this.c;
        }

        public String getText() {
            if (this.b != null) {
                this.a = this.b.toString();
                this.b = null;
            }

            return this.a;
        }

        public void append(String var1) {
            if (this.b == null) {
                this.b = new StringBuilder(this.a);
                this.a = null;
            }

            this.b.append(var1);
        }
    }
}
```

What is interesting is that they have hardcoded new line character check as comparison with `\n` instead of using `System.lineSeparator()` method that for UNIX returns `\n` and for Windows `\r\n`. I'm guessing this is the root of the problem. I have run your test on my Linux machine using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.3.3 and IntelliJ IDEA Community 2017.3 - it worked as expected in both cases. The best way to figure it out would be to run IntelliJ IDEA in debug mode, attach debugger to its JVM, set a breakpoint e.g. here

```
    at com.intellij.execution.testframework.sm.runner.OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.process(OutputToGeneralTestEventsConverter.java:71)
```

and see where the string gets broken. Hope it helps.